# Capture the name of the login user from the session after the user login to the system

Tags: java

I want a help in order to capture or store the user id from the session after the user login to the system.

I have method called 'Login' in the loginBean class, I want after the validation the userId stored in order to use it for example to add records to the DB.

loginBean class:

```
private String userName;
private String password;
public LoginBean() {}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String Login() {
    if (userName == null || userName.trim().length() == 0 || password == null || password.trim().length() == 0) {
        addErrorMessage("please enter your username and password");
        return null;
    }
    UserDto userDto = isRegisteredUser(userName);
    if (userInfoDto == null) {
        addErrorMessage("not validated");
        return null;
    }

    try {
        connect(userName, password);

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        addErrorMessage("wrong userName and password");

        return null;
    }

    return "goMainList";
}
```

userDto class:

```
public class UserDto {

private int userSequence;
private String userName;
private String userLogin;

public int getSequence() {
    return sequence;
}
public void setSequence(int sequence) {
    this.sequence = sequence;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getUserLogin() {
    return userLogin;
}
public void setUserLogin(String userLogin) {
    this.userLogin = userLogin;
}
}
```

I want int the (loginBean) class to save the user id, can anyone help me!

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I want a help to achieve it

Comment: You have to ask a specific question with a specific problem, not an open one which would be more of a discussion or tutor session. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions on stackoverflow and related information like https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.